# Set cookie via Asp.net Web Api which is subdomain for SPA

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api, cookies, setcookie

I have a single page app(based on Asp.net MVC) that communicates with Asp.net Web API. I want to set secure and HttpOnly cookie for authentication via API but all ways did not work which is on the internet that I can find.

Web domain: www.example.com
API: www.api.example.com

I tried a few ways to set a cookie;

1) Using attribute

```
public class CookieAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("tokenName", "tokenValue")
        {
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30),
            Domain = ".example.com",
            HttpOnly = true,
            Secure = true
        };

        actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers.AddCookies(new[] { cookie });

        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
    }
}

[Cookie]
[HttpPost]
[Route("cookie")]
public IHttpActionResult SetCookie()
{
    return Ok();
}
```

2) Via HttpContext

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("cookie")]
public IHttpActionResult SetCookie()
{
   var cookie = new HttpCookie("tokenName")
        {
            Domain = ".example.com",
            Secure = true,
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30),
            HttpOnly = true,
            Value = "tokenValue"
        };

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

        return Ok();
}
```

When I check the cookie on the browser there is nothing. How to set a cookie from web API?

Thanks.

Edit: (For solving)

I thought the problem was related to Asp.net but it was not. The problem is that I was making the request to create a cookie to API using jquery ajax but "withCredentials" prop was missing so because of that I was not able to set a cookie.

```
$.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/cookie",
            crossDomain: true,
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            success: function success(response) {
                // code
            },
            error: function error(response) {
                // code
            }
        });
```

Comment: You have to manage the Cookie and consents... have a look at this tutorial: https://wakeupandcode.com/cookies-and-consent-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but this is for Asp.net Core